# Alienware 17 Ubuntu Dual-boot Issue

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, grubrescue, alienware

I attempted to dual boot Ubuntu on an Alienware 17 running Windows 10. Loaded the installer onto a flash drive, booted from flash drive, and installed it. A window popped up telling me that two parts of the disk would be renamed for swap and ext4 space on the machine; I clicked OK.

After encountering grub rescue following reboot, I booted Ubuntu from a flash drive and ran boot repair. Rebooted and encountered grub rescue again.

Also of note is that I was told by grub repair to make my BIOS boot on sdb disc, but I do not know how to do this.

Any help is appreciated; below is the URL generated by boot repair.

http://paste2.org/nAv89yUD

Exact grub error: "no such device: ab9cdb73-ef21-4a75-a7e0-e31ed5f76dae"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Linux was booting in legacy to my device's second hard drive, which was in RAID configuration and wasn't properly partitioned. I opened linux in trial mode, opened the installer, and partitioned off the second drive. I then restarted my computer and re-installed Ubuntu with the recommended settings (alongside Windows 10) from a flash drive. I set the BIOS to boot in UEFI mode instead of legacy, and it started up as normal. Computer works great; all files are intact; Ubuntu and Windows 10 both run fine.